# Damaged connection when replacing oven element

Tags: electrical, appliances

Our fan oven stopped getting hot the other day so I guessed that it is likely to be the element. Removed the cover and element so I could test it with a multimeter. Unfortunately on one of the connections the plastic thing broke. I am trying to determine what this component  is called so that I can source a replacement. A picture can be found below

[image: What is this?]

And this is what the other one looks like.

[image: Undamaged component]

Any help would be great, the oven is a Baumatic B904SS by the way.

Comment: Respectfully, I don't think this is the right place for your question.  You need to contact the appliance manufacturer or a qualified service center, etc.  We know about concrete and toilets and roofing and stuff.

Comment: @dbracey [Repair of major appliances is officially on-topic.](http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to me like a Faston connecter. The plastic part is the housing.

You might try looking in places like [this](http://www.te.com/catalog/menu/en/17703).